# Problem Counting Number of Times a Link is Clicked in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I have a database with a number of records in it, each with an associated URL.  Currently I have things set up so that when people click on a link for a particular record they get redirected to the appropriate URL.  The code is currently:

```
<%= link_to image_tag( alldata.picture.to_s + ".gif"), alldata.URL_link %>
```

This does its job fine.  I would like to now modify this so when the link is clicked on, a parameter called `:click_count` which is orignally set to 0 for all records.

Reading around, I believe you can do this using something of the following form:

```
<%= link_to image_tag( alldata.picture.to_s + ".gif"), alldata.URL_link, {:controller => params[:controller], :action => "clickcountplusone", :product_name => alldata.product_name}  %>
```

With the following in the controller:

```
def clickcountplusone
  clickeditem = Entiredatabase.find(params[:product_name])
  clickeditem.update_attribute(:click_count => clickeditem.click_count + 1)
end
```

Although this does not produce an error, it also doesn't increase the count number... Could anyone shed any light on the issue?

Comment: I am sure that the :action command should not be in quotes, but not sure where i need to define the function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sintax on `update_attribute` is wrong:

```
clickeditem.update_attribute(:click_count => clickeditem.click_count + 1)
```

should be:

```
clickeditem.update_attribute(:click_count, clickeditem.click_count + 1)
```

Be carefull, `update_attribute` receives a `(name, value)` and `update_attributes` receives a `hash`. More information [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute)

Also take a look to [increment counter](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/increment_counter)

```
Item.increment_counter(:click_count, @item.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, definitely looks a lot more hopeful using what you suggest.  I have put the def statement in the application_helper.  However, I am hitting the issue identified by Frankie and the code tries to run as soon as the page loads.  Just adding :from_link => true doesn't seem to solve the problem.  The link is actually to an external website, so I am not able to put the code in the Show method as he suggested.  Is there a way of stopping the code from running unless the link is clicked on?

Comment: You can create the `show` method and there increment the counter and also redirect to the External Url, so when the user clicks the link it will be redirected to the url by the server. Also can use javascript to send a request to the server when a link is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really need a separate action for this. Instead, simply use the default `show` action, and increment the counter whenever the action is called, like this:

```
def show
   @item = Item.find(params[:id])
   Item.increment_counter(:views, @item.id)
end
```

This will however increment the counter whenever that page is viewed - so if you want to only track views that followed a particular link, you could do something like:

```
def show
   @item = Item.find(params[:id])
   if params[:from_link]
     Item.increment_counter(:views, @item.id)
   end
end
```

And then in your link_to helper, add an extra param:

```
link_to(image_tag("blah.jpg"), item_path, {:from_link => true}
```

Hope this helps.